# How to take a specific output from a module function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, yahoo-finance

FWI: I am very newbish at programming

A module function has 10 in build out puts.

Take the `get_data` function from the fin stock module.

The `get_data` function takes the input, a "stock". And outputs the open, high, low, volume, and ticker.

What I want is just the high output.

---

These are my steps:

```
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import *
#the get_data function lays in stock_info
import datetime

today_data = get_data("Chosen Stock", start_date = today)
today = datetime.date.today()
print(today)
today_data = get_data("ADA-CAD", start_date = today)
print(today_data)
```

---

Now I need that one more step that will take the high output from today_data.
I imagine it would be something like this: `today_data.high()`

These include

Comment: This is how the data loads out:
CAD2021-06-17
               open      high       low  ...  adjclose      volume   ticker
2021-06-17  1.82363  1.887739  1.801735  ...  1.814513  2206857984  ADA-CAD

Answer (score 0):

`today_data` is a [Pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), so if you want to do any significant number-crunching you'll want to `import pandas as pd` in your script.

One feature of DataFrames is that you can get values of a column using the `df_name.col_name` format (with some limitations, read the docs for more). So, you can simply do

```
print(today_data.high)
```

and it will print out the column, with the index/indices on the left:

```
2021-06-17    1.887739
```

The other column names are `['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'adjclose', 'volume', 'ticker']`, if you want to get any other info about the stock.

To just get the value of today's high, you can select the first (and only) row in the `"high"` column like so:

```
print(today_data.high[0])
```

which gives you:

```
1.887738585472107
```

Remember that indexing in Python is 0-based.

There are lots of good tutorials out there on Pandas and working with dataframes, including [on their website](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html).